# uninitialized constant when reloading after enabling zeitwerk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zeitwerk

Having some trouble working out the migration from Classic to Zeitwerk.

After enabling zeitwerk and running `rails s`, everything seems to work. Then after saving a .rb file and refreshing, I'm seeing an "uninitialized constant" error when trying to require a file from the top level `/lib`.

Something is misconfigured w/ reloading, but I'm scratching my head trying to work out the details. I was under the impression that having a top level `/lib` folder is fine and using `require` to load files in that directory is compatible with Zeitwerk, but now I'm not so sure... ideas as to what I'm getting wrong?

Note: I'm not currently setting any specific `eager_load_paths` or `autoload_paths`

EDIT: updated with logging output as suggested by [@Xavier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8362448/xavier-noria)

```
Zeitwerk@rails.main: module CustomModule autovivified from directory *********/app/workers/custom_module
Zeitwerk@rails.main: autoload set for CustomModule::Profiler, to be loaded from *********/app/workers/custom_module/profiler.rb
Zeitwerk@rails.main: autoload set for CustomModule::AnotherProfiler, to be loaded from *********/app/workers/custom_module/another_profiler.rb

NameError - uninitialized constant CustomModule::AttributeParser
Did you mean?  NameParserConstants:
  app/models/user.rb:180:in `first_name'
  app/middleware/catch_json_parse_errors.rb:8:in `call'
  app/middleware/decompress_requests.rb:22:in `call'
```

Comment: Yes, it is compatible. Could you please throw `Rails.autoloaders.log!` in `config/application.rb`, trigger the error, and share the traces?

Comment: Ah! you know what... there's a `CustomModule` defined in `/app/workers` and a `CustomModule` defined in `/lib`. Looks like the `/app/workers` version is loading last and appears to be overwriting the version in `/lib`

Comment: Exactly, is a case of https://github.com/fxn/zeitwerk#reopening-third-party-namespaces. The `require` is idempotent, the constant is reloaded, so child constants from the namespace defined in `lib` are no longer reloaded. You need to define `CustomModule` during boot, so that the autoloader knows it does not manage that namespace (it descends automatically).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The namespace `CustomModule` is shared in parts of the project that are reloadable (under `app`), and also in parts where is not (under `lib`).

This is fine, it is supported. You only need to deliberately think about load priorities, because if `lib` defines `CustomModule::Foo` and Rails believes `CustomModule` is reloadable, on reload nobody is loading `CustomModule::Foo` again, and `require` is idempotent, so `CustomModule::Foo` won't be found anymore.

The solution is to make sure `lib` *defines* the namespace, and Rails autoloaders *reopen* it. Essentially same as documented [here](https://github.com/fxn/zeitwerk#reopening-third-party-namespaces). This can be done by issuing a `require` in an initializer that loads the namespace from `lib`, for example.

That way, when the autoloader scans the file system, it knows it is not responsible for managing `CustomModule`. It will descend. If there are child constants there everything will work as usual, and those constants will be reloaded, but the namespace itself won't.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! I ended up just altering one of the module’s names (and folder) to avoid the confusion

Comment: That's a great solution, less dragons and no need for an artificial `require` to force load order. 